# Richfaces drag and drop object not defined?

Tags: drag-and-drop, richfaces

Mozilla is spitting out

> DnD is not defined

errors on all of my rich:dragSupport and rich:dropSupport tags. When I check out the generated javascript the DnD object is where it should be and things look ok. Any ideas on why my DnD object is not defined? Has anyone come accross gotchas with using richfaces dnd?

We are using Richfaces 3.2.1 (drag and drop started in 3.0.0 acording to [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_dragSupport.html))

An example of how we are using this:

```
<a4j:outputPanel><rich:panel>
    <rich:dropSupport dropListener="#{myBean.dropAction}>
        <a4j:actionParam value="#{someData}" name="paramData" />
    </rich:dropSupport>

    <a4j:repeat value="#{myBean.list}" var="item">
        <a4j:outputPanel>
        <rich:panel>
                <rich:dragSupport dragValue="#{someOtherData}">
            <a4j:actionparam value="#{someOtherOtherData}" name="secondParam" />
            <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"></h:outputText>
        </rich:dragSupport>
        </rich:panel>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
    </a4j:repeat>
</rich:panel></a4j:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem: typo in naming of JBoss portlet deployment xml files

Other things to check (from week of research):
Are you deploying the [necessary richfaces jar files](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/GettingStarted.html)?
Do you have other js scripts that are causing namespace issues like jQuery or prototype?

Answer (score 0):

It's an old thread, but my answer is: Inside tag < rich:dragSupport/>, must be included < rich:dndParam>.
See http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dragSupport.jsf?tab=usage&cid=289435 for more information.

PD: Sorry for my rustic English, I'm from Argentina...

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. On Stack Overflow it is fine to reply to old threads since they may still be used by lots of people for new problems. It is my understanding that the `dndParam` is only required if there are parameters to be sent. Is this not the case? PS. Su Inglés es mejor que mi español! Bienvenida!