# How to create draggable component with RichFaces?

Tags: jsf, drag-and-drop, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I try  to make draggable components and to do this I am based on this example:
http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dragSupport.jsf

and i started with this example but the component does not give any indication that is draggable:

```
    <!---------------- Indicator -------->
    <rich:dragIndicator id="indicator" />
    <h:form>
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><rich:panel>
                    <rich:tree>
                        ...
                    </rich:tree>
                </rich:panel></td>
                <td valign="top"><rich:panel id="afficherTest">
                    <rich:dataGrid value="#{afficherTestBean.listTest}" var="test"
                        columns="2" elements="6" width="600px">
                        <rich:panel style="cursor: move">
                                   <!---------------draggable Zone-------------------->
                            <rich:dragSupport dragIndicator=":indicator"
                                dragType="#{test.nomTest}" dragValue="#{test.nomTest}">
                                <rich:dndParam name="label" value="#{test.nomTest}" />
                            </rich:dragSupport>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{test.categorie}"></h:outputText>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                                <h:outputText value="Nom Test:" styleClass="label"></h:outputText>
                                <h:outputText value="#{test.nomTest}" />
                                <h:outputText value="Description Test:" styleClass="label"></h:outputText>
                                <h:outputText value="{test.description}" />
                                <a4j:commandLink value="Ajouter"></a4j:commandLink>
                            </h:panelGrid>

                        </rich:panel>
                        <f:facet name="footer">
                            <rich:datascroller></rich:datascroller>
                        </f:facet>

                    </rich:dataGrid>
                </rich:panel></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </h:form>

    </html>
```

please help me to create draggable component,i need your help ):'

Comment: is there something wrong in my code??

Comment: If the example doesn't work for you then it probably is something behind the scenes. Are there any js errors? I had my own issues with DnD and made notes at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501169/richfaces-drag-and-drop-object-not-defined/1533863#1533863